# OnTouch listener not working in relativelayout which included mapfragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, ontouchlistener, android-relativelayout

in fragment i need to implement ontouch listener to relativelayout which included map fragment and i have made layouts as when i click map button mapview visible, same as done with listview. i have to detect when user touch over map, also i made ontouch for partmap layout which doesn't work.anyone plz.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/partMap"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:alpha="0.0">
    <fragment

        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/R_noPropertiesMatchMap"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="No properties match your search"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Please change the zoom or your filters"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/R_noOnlyUS"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Invalid address"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv3"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Realy is only available in the US"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/R_notgeoloc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Oops! We are unable to find your location."
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv3"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Please check your system preferences to make sure geolocation is enabled."
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>`<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/partone"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    >

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_listing"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/R_Loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/L_no_fav_homes"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_no_fav_homes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:src="@drawable/no_homes" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_fav_properties"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/iv_no_fav_homes"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="No properties match your search"
                android:textColor="#78797B"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_facebookmessage"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_fav_properties"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Please change your filters"
                android:textColor="#ADAEB0"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" >
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/L_out_us"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_no_us"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:src="@drawable/out_usa" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_error"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/iv_no_us"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Invalid address"
                android:textColor="#78797B"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_error_2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text_error"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Realy is only available in the US"
                android:textColor="#ADAEB0"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tv_startsearching_clear"
                style="@style/btnStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Clear filter"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/L_notgeoloc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/notgeoloc" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_error45"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/iv_no_us"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Oops! We are unable to find your location."
            android:textColor="#78797B"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_error_3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_error"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Please check your system preferences to make sure geolocation is enabled."
            android:textColor="#ADAEB0"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/Footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#006AA8"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ShowMap"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Map"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ShowNearby"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Nearby"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ClearFilters"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Clear filters"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout></RelativeLayout>`
```

Comment: try to be specific on your question.. do you want to add touch for your map fragment or to the relative layout?

Comment: i want ontouch for relative layout .

Comment: edited my post ..i hope now you catch the point.i think

Comment: are you still in the question? you can easily use ontouch for the relative layout as we all do for buttons...

Comment: tnx for reply..fixed.

Comment: how did you fix? It will be helpful for others..